# How to create a stored procedure to update database after table edit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, c#, extended-stored-procedure

In a C# website application with a database, I set a gridView table so that I could edit the values in the table by row, but it appears that I need a stored procedure to do that.

Below is the stored procedure along with the errors I get when trying to use/run it. Please help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureGridView1_RowUpdated] 
    @Property_ID INT,
    @Type_ID INT,
    @Property_Name TEXT,
    @Address VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Coordinates NUMERIC(18, 0),
    @Property_Description TEXT,
    @Map IMAGE,
    @Landlord_ID INT,
    @BuildingSize INT,
    @Allowance MONEY,
    @Amenities TEXT,
    @Attachedfiles_ID INT,
    @UpdatedDate DATE,
    @ParkingRatio TEXT,
    @Expenses MONEY,
    @Stat INT
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM PROPERTY)
       SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

    UPDATE [PROPERTY]
    SET [Property_ID] = @Property_ID,
        [Type_ID] = @Type_ID,
        [Property_Name] = @Property_Name,
        [Address] = @Address,
        [Coordinates] = @Coordinates,
        [Property_Descrption] = @Property_Description,
        [Map] = @Map,
        [Landlord_ID] = @Landlord_ID,
        [BuildingSize] = @BuildingsizE,
        [Allowance] = @AllowancE,
        [Amenities] = @Amenities,
        [AttachedFiles_ID] = @AttachedfileS_ID,
        [UpdatedDate] = @UpdatedDate,
        [ParkingRatio] = @ParkingRatio,
        [Expenses] = @Expenses,
        [Stat] = @Stat;
```

A test query using the procedure:

```
USE [C:\USERS\MydataBase.MDF]
GO

DECLARE @return_value Int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[ProcedureGridView1_RowUpdated] 
  @Property_ID = 4,
  @Type_ID = 4,
  @Property_Name = N'TEST',
  @Address = N'TEST',
  @Coordinates = 11,
  @Property_Description = N'TEST',
  @Map = NULL,
  @Landlord_ID = 1,
  @BuildingSize = 5000,
  @Allowance = 50,
  @Amenities = N'3',
  @Attachedfiles_ID = 1,
  @UpdatedDate = 10/15/2015,
  @ParkingRatio = N';35',
  @Expenses = 46,
  @Stat = 2

SELECT @return_value as 'Return Value'
GO
```

Errors when trying to run the stored procedure:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Procedure or function
>   ProcedureGridView1_RowUpdated has too many arguments specified.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or
>   function ProcedureGridView1_RowUpdated has too many arguments
>   specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function
>   ProcedureGridView1_RowUpdated has too many arguments specified.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) +2523746
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) +81
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +609
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +225
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2064
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +375
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +337
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +280
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand
>   command, DataSourceOperation operation) +392
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +670
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary
>   values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback
>   callback) +106
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32
>   rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1210
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean
>   causesValidation, String validationGroup) +877
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +89 System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +90 System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
>   +121 System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +161
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +9748498 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1738

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.57.0

Comment: If you're passing in a date, it must be a string, and please use YYYYMMDD it works with all regional settings: @UpdatedDate = '20151015'

Comment: No sure if you intended so, but it's easy to assume all the set commands are inside the if but actually only the first one is -- but changing ansi_nulls based on row existence sounds something i really don't recommend doing

Comment: If you are using the built in updates in c# you need to map the columns in the data grid to the parameters in the stored procedure. If you have additional custom columns in the data grid the built-in update methods are going to map them and that probably what is causing the exception.  You will need to manually map the data grid columns to the command parameters. [MSDN Insert Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @UpdatedDate = '20151015' did not make a difference..............................Removed the if statement, but did not make a difference.....Will look into the Mapping

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: The error clearly says: the way you're calling this stored procedure from your ASP.NET code is wrong - you're providing **too many parameters** - you need to show us **that code** - not your T-SQL stuff ....